# yet with a past simple in that case

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is the best

The records ordered **had not been released yet** so the label decided to send some free records to make him  wait.

At that time the records ordered  **were not released yet**so the label decided to send some free records to make him wait .

So in which cases is it possible to use yet with past simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main sense in which the word yet is used is up till now or then; by this time or by that time.

So the use of "at that time" along with "yet" in the second sentence sounds redundant. I think the sentence in the past simple Will be OK if you omit "at that time" and put a comma before "so" in this sentence.

The first sentence is OK and the better option; it only needs a comma before the conjunction "so".